# Blurry images in Android browser and WebView

Tags: android, android-image

For my android application, I need to show certain images in a `WebView`. The application runs on Android 2.1 (API 7) and onward. The images contain table soft text and the problem I am facing is that in Android versions 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 etc, they are always blurry while in newer versions, such as 4.0.3, they are sharp. I have tested high/low resolution images but the results are the same.

Why is it so?

Comment: If it's any help, I often find that when I view images on my Android device in the default browser, the image is often of low quality and pixelated. You could download the high def image, and show it in an image view?

Comment: I want to avoid this approach because the number of images is large and they would take a lot of space on the client side if they are saved locally.

Comment: You could download the image, show it in the image view, but not save it locally. It needs only to be temporarily cached :-)